# How to add text to a textbox, starting from bottom to top

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working the famous rock paper scissor game. If you win the game after 10 rounds, a window shows, and it asks for a username. If none is given, "ANONIEM" is showing. So every time I start a new game, and win 10 rounds against the computer, the next window shows, again asking for a username, and adding the log to a `TextBlock`. So my code is working placing it from the top to the bottom like every other system normally works.

My question is:

- Is it possible, when I press "save", and a new line is added to the textblock, and starts from the bottom of the textblock to the top, but not going over the top, and just press all the other text down?
- Or is it possible to sort it on time everytime I add a new line?

What I have right now is:

- ANONIEM - PC  10 - 2  (02:30:01)
- ANONIEM - PC  5 - 10  (02:40:08)
- ANONIEM - PC  8 - 10  (02:50:16)

What I need it to do is:

- ANONIEM - PC  8 - 10  (02:50:16)
- ANONIEM - PC  5 - 10  (02:40:08)
- ANONIEM - PC  10 - 2  (02:30:01)

My code:

```cs
if (ronde > 0)
{
    if (txtGebruikersnaam.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        txtScoreLog5.Text +=  "ANONIEM" + " - PC " + scorespeler + " - " + scorepc + " (" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ")" + "\r\n";
    }
    else if (txtGebruikersnaam.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        txtScoreLog5.Text += txtGebruikersnaam.Text + " - PC " + scorespeler + " - " + scorepc + " (" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ")" + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

- what it currently do:
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/thoE9.png]
- what I need it to do:
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o261.png]

Answer (score 1):

Just add the new text to the beginning of the TextBlock's text like this:

```
if (ronde > 0)
{
    string result = txtGebruikersnaam.Text.Length == 0 ? "ANONIEM" : txtGebruikersnaam.Text

    txtScoreLog5.Text = result + " - PC " + scorespeler + " - " + scorepc + " (" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ")" + "\r\n" +  txtScoreLog5.Text;
}
```